# Asp.Net Core Dependency Injection through Annotation like Spring MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i inject using annotation which is like a feature of Spring MVC

```
public class AccountController :Controller
{

[Injected] // Need like this annotation
private AccountService _accountService;

public AccountController(){

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Unity Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507453(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Here is an example:

```
public class MyObject
{
  private SomeOtherObject _dependentObject;

  [Dependency]
  public SomeOtherObject DependentObject 
  {
    get { return _dependentObject; }
    set { _dependentObject = value; }
  }
}
```

And here is the resolution:

```
IUnityContainer uContainer = new UnityContainer();
MyObject myInstance = uContainer.Resolve<MyObject>();

// now access the property containing the dependency
SomeOtherObject depObj = myInstance.DependentObject;
```

Comment: dotnet core has its own DI, so using that is better.

Comment: @inthevortex "using that is better" ... is not true. It depends on your requirements. Default mechanisme has for example no property injection or there are di frameworks with have better performance on runtime or on startup.

Comment: @Tester true, if requirements aren't met by it then there are frameworks for it.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net core application no need to mention as injected annotation.you need to change your service as interface driven.

In solution startup page add below shown code before  services.AddMvc();

```
        services.AddTransient<IInterface, Service>();
```

and in controller make change as

```
public class AccountController :Controller
{ 
   private IAccountService _accountService;
   public AccountController(IAccountService accountService){
       _accountService = accountService;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Saneesh what are the pros and cons of ASP DI/IoC vs the way that Java Spring/Java EE handle it? I am just starting to explore dot net eco.

Comment: Hi asp.net core IoC mainly designed and dedicated for prevent memory leakage, mock testing and thread safe. But with respect to 3 types of Ioc scope it's feature application need to design and develop to get full advantage..